# Static or dynamic binding in the code?

Tags: java, binding

```
class A
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("in A");
    }

    public static void invoke(A x)
    {
        x.display();
    }
}
```

What kind of binding (static or dynamic) would this code represent? I would also appreciate reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one `displayables`, create an interface delaring a display method.

your displyables implement the interface. So

```
interface Displayable {void display();}

class A implements Displayable {
    public void display() {System.out.println("in A");}
}
class B implements Displayable {
    public void display() {System.out.println("in B");}
}
```

your invoke method is

```
public static void invoke(Displayable x) {x.display();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created an object of A class and calling the method `display()` under the `invoke()` method. Compiler would be able to resolve this binding during compile-time. Therefore, this is a static binding.

As for dynamic binding (late binding) you need to have ambiguous type object which the time to determine at run time. As the above method runs everything determined during compile so this is why it is static binding.